# NameError line 50 for item in storeProducts , name 'storeProducts' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with my python program where I'm trying to create a class that holds data about an item in a retail store. I don't know why it's giving me NameError. Also, would it be possible to convert the data in storeProducts list into a dictionary and still have it displayed as a table

```
class Products:
    def __init__(self,productId,description,quantity,price):
        self.productId = productId
        self.description = description
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = price

    def set_productId(self,productId):
        self.__productId = productId

    def set_description(self,description):
        self.__description = description

    def set_quantity(self,quantity):
        self.__quantity = quantity


    def set_price(self,price):
        self.__price = price

    def get_productId(self,productId):
        return self.__productId 

    def get_description(self,description):
        return self.__description

    def get_quantity(self,quantity):
        return self.__quantity

    def get_price(self,price):
        return self.__price

    def __str__(self):
        return'Products:'+ 'title:' + self.title+', description:' + self.description + \
            ' ,quantity' + self.quantity + ', price:' + self.price

def main():
    storeProducts = [[1,'Jacket',1,59.95],
                 [2, 'Designer Jeans' , 40, 34.95],
                 [3, 'Shirt' , 20, 24.95],]
print=(': Product ID : Description : Quantity : Price : ')

for item in storeProducts:
    print(':',item[0],''*(9-len(str(item[0]))), ':',
          item[1],''*(11-len(item[1])),':',
          item[2],''*(8-len(str(item[2]))),':',
          item[3],''*(5-len(str(item[3]))))


main()
```

Comment: Did you really mean to assign to `print`?

Comment: Also, this `print` and the following `for` loop should be indented to be part of `main`

Answer (score -1):

If you copy-pasted the code properly, there's a clear indentation problem in your `main` function.